# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' for older version of pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to install PyTorch 0.4.0 with cuda9.0 to use [this](https://github.com/iMoonLab/MeshNet) repository.
However, after installing, when I try to import PyTorch by doing `import torch`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I am following [pytorch's official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) to install the package.
 Here is the commands I used for installing pytorch:
`conda install pytorch=0.4.0 cuda90 -c pytorch`

Comment: If conda installed it successfully, then you're not using the same python interpreter as conda.

Comment: I think I am, because I installed it in a conda venv and I'm using python from that venv itself.

Comment: Check it by `which python` first.